# Loop through nested relation in view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to loop through some data in my blade view. This is my database setup:

[image]

What I would like to have in my view is the following:

[image]

So I can loop through the days and then order the tasks by the category they are in. I'm not experienced with Laravel and I'm having difficulties on ordering the tasks by category in the best way.

In my **Days** Model I have:

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Task');
}
```

In my **Task** Model I have:

```
public function days()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Day');
}

public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

In my **Category** Model I have:

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Task');
}
```

In my controller I now only have:

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::all();

    return view('app.blade.php', compact('categories'));
}
```

But how can I make sure to order them by days and then by category? Help much appreciated.

Comment: You should have pivot table at least for [ManyToMany](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)  relation..

Comment: @BasheerAhmed, yes sorry. My picture wasn't correct. Should now be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try as following:

```
$days = Days::with('tasks.category')->get();

$days = $days->map(function ($day) {
    $day->tasks = $day->tasks->groupBy('category_id');

    return $day;
});
```

Check it how it is converted after groupBy() method

```
dd($days);
```

then in your view you can do as:

```
@foreach ($days as $day)
    {{ $day->name }}
    @foreach ($days->tasks as $tasks)
        {{ $tasks->first()->category->name }}
        @foreach ($tasks as $task)
            {{ $task->name }}
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

*Note - I have not tested it but you can give it a try.*